# Passing in config file for the production instance of my Meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor

So on my local machine, when I boot up the Meteor app, I pass in a json file to specify app settings like this

```
meteor --settings local.json
```

This seems to work. However, as specified in the meteor.com documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying) when deploying the app in your own infrastructure, you need to bundle up your app using "meteor bundle" and then run it as node instance like so

```
PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js
```

I'm able to do this and have the app deployed on my server. However, I'm not sure how I'm meant to pass the json file with my config settings in.

```
PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp --settings prod.json node bundle/main.js
PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js --settings prod.json
```

Is `--settings` a Meteor thing or a Node thing? If it's the latter, how do I pass in my JSON file?

Comment: I dont understand why is this put on hold? Its a legit question

Comment: @Akshat : You've answered my question so it doesn't bother me, but yeah, it does seem a bit strange that this question would be off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @JakeGould: maybe you closed this in a hurry; the question is definitely on-topic. Please revise.

Comment: Meteor [issue 961](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/961) refers to this.

Comment: @JakeGould given that you haven't seem to have answered any questions about Meteor, I think your close vote may have been misguided - the first vote always brings others. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Hey @Seph, looks like you [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20918293/revisions) this question by mistake. More careful this time please?

Comment: This question was closed because it was a 'general computing' question.  How is a specific config question about a specific framework a 'general computing question'?  Don't the closers have anything better to do with their time?  I ran into this problem too, so I'm really glad this was reopened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--settings` is a meteor thing.

In production you can use the environmental variable instead since `--settings` is meant for use with `meteor run` or just `meteor`

From the docs:

> Meteor.settings contains deployment-specific configuration options. You can initialize settings by passing the --settings option (which takes a file containing JSON data) to meteor run or meteor deploy, or by setting your server process's METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable to a JSON string

So something like this could work:

```
PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat prod.json) node bundle/main.js
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for METEOR_SETTINGS to take a file instead of a string though? Putting in METEOR_SETTINGS=prod.json gives me a "Error: Settings are not valid JSON" error. Putting in METEOR_SETTINGS={} allows me to boot up the app, but of course, the configuration is not set.

Comment: Yes it is possible have a look at the screencast at https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/sg3ejYnmhxpBNoWan you basically use `$(cat file.json)`

Comment: @Diskdrive: You'll have to [+1 this Meteor issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1116#issuecomment-48982351) to pass settings via config files. I also find it very cumbersome, and most often impossible, to pass complex settings via a one-line environment variable.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have to escape anything from that `cat`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a start script as shown here:

https://www.eventedmind.com/classes/setting-up-meteor-projects/a-sample-start-script

The code for it is here: https://github.com/cmather/meteor-start.

A script like this make it easy to use different environments for development vs production as well.